# angularjs apply ng-show to a inputs-placehoder-icon

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'd like to change the placeholder-icon of a ionic-input element.
Therfore I use a ng-show in two different icons. In the controller I compare two password-fields of equality. If they are equal, a checkmark is shown, if not a decline-icon is shown.

html:

```
<label class="item item-input">
     <input type="password" name="newPasswordVerify" placeholder="retype new password" ng-model="user.newPasswordVerify"/>
     <i ng-show="passCorrect"  class="icon ion-ios7-close-empty placeholder-icon"></i>
     <i ng-show="!passCorrect"  class="icon ion-ios7-checkmark-empty placeholder-icon" ></i>
</label>
```

controller:

```
$scope.$watch('user.newPasswordVerify', function() {

       if($scope.user.newPasswordVerify!=="")
       {
           if($scope.user.newPasswordVerify.equals($scope.user.newPassword))
                   $scope.passCorrect = true;
           else
                   $scope.passCorrect = false;
       }
});
```

I get a correct console-output, but the dom doesn't apply the changes.

Edit: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcelly/jLjg1b5y/1/)

Comment: Not the problem you asked, but you're missing the `=` between `name` and `newPasswordVerify` on your input tag.

Comment: Did you try `$scope.$apply();`?

Comment: yes, i tried $scope.$apply as well as $timout(fn(){$scope.passCorrect = true/false},0);

Comment: Maybe you could create a jsfiddle ;)

Comment: Fiddle up, found the problem. See comment below

Comment: @marcel update the question with the answer, or post the answer and accept it, however trivial it may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.user.newPasswordVerify!==""
```

didn't work. I replaced it with

```
$scope.user.newPasswordVerify.charAt(0)
```

and it works

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="frm">
  <label class="item item-input">
       <input type="password" name="newPasswordVerify" placeholder="retype new password" ng-model="user.newPasswordVerify"/>
       <i ng-show="passCorrect"  class="icon ion-ios7-close-empty placeholder-icon"></i>
       <i ng-show="!passCorrect"  class="icon ion-ios7-checkmark-empty placeholder-icon" ></i>
  </label>
</form>
```

When you give a `<form>` tag a name Angular will assign it a `FormController` to manage input validation. It's recommended to use that for validation because the life-cycle of model data can varry depending upon how you've setup the form. What's being shown on the page isn't always what is in the model data.

Each `ngModel` directive will create a `ngModelController` for that directive that allows you to add `$validator` rules.

```
 $scope.frm.newPasswordVerify.$validator.badPassword = function(modelValue,viewValue){
      var value = modelValue || viewValue;
      return $scope.user.newPassword == value;
 };
```

The above will pass validation (true) if the two passwords match, otherwise it will fail. When it fails the CSS class `ng-invalid-bad-password` will be assigned to the input. Likewise `ng-valid-bad-password` when be assigned when true.

The form will have a `$error` flag set to true for `badPassword` to match validation.

```
 <i ng-show="!frm.$error.badPassword"  class="icon ion-ios7-close-empty placeholder-icon"></i>
 <i ng-show="frm.$error.badPassword"  class="icon ion-ios7-checkmark-empty placeholder-icon" ></i>
```

Comment: This is compilcated, I've got to check this out.